# How to custom format date in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, date

I have this format in my input program: "2022-03-07T09:31:49.06251Z" and I need change to "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS"

Note, the timezone is the same.

**sample:**

2022-01-26T14:57:33.2400054Z   => 20220126 14:57:33

I find any code whith `date.fromisoformat` and/or `.isoformat()` but is not custom format.

**EDIT:**

I try this: `datetime.strptime("2022-03-08T09:57:43.7227461Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")` but I have this error:

`[ERROR] ValueError: time data '2022-03-08T09:57:43.7227461Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`

Comment: use `datetime` package. `my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-03-07T09:31:49.06251Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")` then you have a ´datetime.datetime´ object. Now you can format this datetime object any way you want. In your case `my_date.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @BijayRegmi, Your code work with your input but not with mine (`2022-03-07T09:59:27.3369598Z`) zone is different

Comment: Looks like `datetime.strptime` and `%f` only accepts microseconds with 6 digits, so **7227461** will raise the unmaching error. Check the [spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library called dateutil.

```
from dateutil import parser
parsed_date = parser.parse('2022-03-07T09:31:49.06251Z')
print(parsed_date)
>>> datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 7, 9, 31, 49, 62510, tzinfo=tzutc())
print(parsed_date.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> '20220307 09:31:49'
```